# Unable to complete password reset in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, rails-activerecord, forgot-password

I am trying to complete a password reset feature for my Rails application. I have all of my routes and views in place and they all work with out a problem. When the user clicks on the email sent by the system that is generated with the password reset token, they are taken to the password reset view. However when the user submits the form (valid or not) to update the User record with the new password, the view simply reloads with no errors or not. I have tried multiple configurations with no luck. I feel like it has to do with my strong parameters, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

This is the url that is generated for the password reset view

```
http://localhost:3000/password_resets/X6hrhVsJX2nB8-U7Zp9-7Q/edit
```

This is what I have for my password reset controller:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])

    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
        flash[:notice] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    elseif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Password reset was successful. Please sign in."
        redirect_to(:controller => 'auth', :action => 'get_sign_in')
    else
        render(:edit)
    end
end

private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

This is what my form looks like

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <%= f.password_field(:password, class: 'validate') %>
        <%= f.label :password %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, class: 'validate') %>
        <label for="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="action">Update Password
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are my routes that I am using

```
resources :password_resets

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Here are the server logs that I am getting during the action

```
Started PUT "/password_resets/82o6bWWIdpUg4jAnMcJqNQ" for ::1 at 2015-07-09 06:10:49 -0500
Processing by PasswordResetsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"NuwgHyhpeYE+fhPM8Cl6tTJPTTAGeFGYnsAlvVN4tg0utO3795qTRZno7bNdDUDL9rIrki5v8VF2zP3UC2auCQ==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "id"=>"82o6bWWIdpUg4jAnMcJqNQ"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`password_reset_token` = '82o6bWWIdpUg4jAnMcJqNQ' LIMIT 1
Rendered partials/_user_errors.html.erb (0.2ms)
Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (86.4ms)
Rendered password_resets/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (92.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 188ms (Views: 186.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Routing for these paths from `routes.rb` would help as well.

Comment: Are you using an authentification gem, or is it your own authentification system ? I don't recall having to code anything when using devise, this is the kind of stuff  that's already taken care of by the gem. If the view simply reload without any error it means your code always execute render(:edit) so your previous condition are never true.

Comment: No I am not. All of my authentication is from scratch. Essentially that is my question. Why is my elseif.update_attributes getting skipped every single time the code runs.

Comment: update_attributes is expecting a Hash parameter to update your model. If you put a debug point before render(:edit) and check @user.errors you will see the errors that were triggered when rails tried to update your model.

Comment: Please post your server log generated when submitting the form

Comment: I have added my console server logs.